# jQuery - toggle between multiple divs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I've found here, on Stackoverflow, function, which should toggle between multiple divs. I tried it in JSFiddle and it worked. But for me, on website, it doesn't work. I am really not good at javascript / jQuery, so I will be really glad for any help! And one more thing - is it possible to set link, that I just clicked on add class "active", that it would have underline or something, to see which section is selected?? 
Thanks!
-- FIDDLE HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/vkmw86bp/

Code is below.

HTML:

```
      <div id="sluzby-nabidka" class="section">
        <div class="sluz"><a href="#" data-slide-id="#slidingDiv">div 1</a></div>
        <div class="sluz"><a href="#" data-slide-id="#slidingDiv_2">div 2</a></div>
        <div class="sluz"><a href="#" data-slide-id="#slidingDiv_3">div 3</a></div>
        <div class="sluz"><a href="#" data-slide-id="#slidingDiv_4">div 4</a></div>
        <div class="sluz"><a href="#" data-slide-id="#slidingDiv_5">div 5</a></div>


      </div>



      <div id="text-sluzba" class="section">

<div id="slidingDiv" class="slide-div">1</div>
<div id="slidingDiv_2" class="slide-div" style="display:none;">2</div>
<div id="slidingDiv_3" class="slide-div" style="display:none;">3</div>
<div id="slidingDiv_4" class="slide-div" style="display:none;">4</div>
<div id="slidingDiv_5" class="slide-div" style="display:none;">5</div>

      </div>
```

JS:

```
$.fn.showHide = function (options) {

    //default vars for the plugin
    var defaults = {
        speed: 1000,
        easing: '',
        changeText: 0,
        showText: 'Show',
        hideText: 'Hide',
        slideDiv: '.slide-div'
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            $(options.slideDiv).hide();
            // this var stores which button you've clicked
            var toggleClick = $(this),
                toggleDiv = $(this).data('slide-id');
            // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
            $(toggleDiv).fadeToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function () {
                // this only fires once the animation is completed
                // if(options.changeText==0){
                //$(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
                //}

            });


        });

    });

};

$('a').showHide({'slideDiv' : '.slide-div'});
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Have you checked the console log (F12)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't have enough reputation yet to add a comment, I'll speak to the issue and then ask for more information, if necessary.

When I loaded your JSFiddle, it didn't work because a JQuery library was not included in the fiddle itself. Once I switched the Frameworks & Extensions selection to *any* JQuery library, I hit Run and it worked. So this, IMO, means that your JQuery import is either in the wrong place in the HTML DOM, or you're not waiting for the DOM to be ready before hitting the code you provided. Som examples:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
        <!-- normally, JQuery script gets added here -->
        <script type="javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<!-- then, import the above code here, either as a separate JS file or inside some <script></script> tags -->
        <script type="javascript" src="path/to/showHide.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, you should wrap the code you provided with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

This will ensure that the JQuery code doesn't execute until the DOM is loaded. It seems to me that **your code is running before the DOM is ready so the lookup isn't finding any anchor tags to attach the showHide functionality to** when you make this call:

```
$('a').showHide({'slideDiv' : '.slide-div'});
```

Comment: I had jQuery lib included in my website's file, when I've added `$(document).ready(function() {` it has started to work! Thank you! And btw, would you know how to add class "active" to the link I've just clicked on?

Comment: I added some script tags to make what I'm talking about more obvious :)

Comment: inside the $(this).click(function() {}); code, place $('a').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active'); This will remove the active class from ALL anchor tags and then add active to the currently clicked anchor tag